# OAuthlib thinks request is insecure because of reverse proxy

Tags: django, https, google-oauth, reverse-proxy, google-api-python-client

I have noticed that for every request, `request.scheme` is http. I can't find any official source why, but I have been told by my peers this is because of Cloudflare acting as reverse proxy and a tls terminator, causing my server's hosting provider to see http instead of https.

One part of my app uses the Google Classroom API, and I have configured a callback to a secure endpoint of my server. Upon attempting to fetch a token from the callback's absolute uri, oauthlib raises `oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749.errors.InsecureTransportError: (insecure_transport) OAuth 2 MUST utilize https.` because it thinks the request is http and insecure. I have researched and found out I can set `os.environ['OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT'] = '1'` to mitigate this issue, but I am hesitant to do so because I am unsure if that compromises security.

My thought process is to manually change the request url to https when I'm absolutely sure it is secure. Inspecting `request.META` to find which headers are set in the case of a reverse proxied http request, the code looks like this:

```py
authorization_response = request.build_absolute_uri()
if (
    authorization_response.startswith("http://") and
    request.META["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO"] == "https" and
    request.META["HTTP_ORIGIN"].startswith("https") and
    json.loads(request.META["HTTP_CF_VISITOR"])['scheme'] == "https"
):
    authorization_response = "https://" + authorization_response[7:]

... fetch the token passing authorization_response and etc
```

which seems to work.

Considering how little information I could find this online, I was wondering if this is a best practice and if there's a better way of letting oauthlib know the request is secure. Or, since my domain has HSTS preload, is this all unnecessary and I can get away with setting `os.environ['OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT'] = '1'`?

Comment: I have similar situation with Kubernetes. My Flask app runs in Docker on port 80, but is fronted by Kubernetes as https (in Enterprise scenario). I opted for the environment variable for now, but interested in responses to this.